# How to create link element with image as anchor with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I know how to create elements with jquery using something like:

```
$('<div/>').appendTo('body');
```

How can I create this:

```
<a href=""><img src="" /></a>
```

Using the same technique?

Comment: what's your difficulties actually???

Comment: `$('<a href=""><img src="" /></a>').appendTo('body');` **or** `$('<a href=""></a>').append('<img src="" />').appendTo('body');`, *and many other flavours.*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
$('<img />').attr({
  src:'some image url',
  width:'width in intiger',
  height:'integer'
}).appendTo($('<a />').attr({
  href:'somelink'
}).appendTo($('#someElement')));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can first select the html element using jquery and then use the "html()" method to set the desired html. Here is a sample:

```
$('div.demo-container')
  .html('<a href=""><img src="" /></a>');
```

The only thing is that you should be able to uniquely identify the desired div that you want to alter. Probably by setting id or class.

Answer (score 2):

Well.. you can do: `$('<a href="http://mysite.com"><img src="/img/img.jpg" /></a>').appendTo('#myDIV')`

Answer (score 2):

First you need to figure out if there is a wrapping element around where you would like to inject this content. In jquery you would use the function:

```
$('.inner').append('<p>Test</p>');
```

Lets say this was your dom element:

```
<h2>Greetings</h2>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="inner">Hello</div>
    <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

Any items with the class ".inner" will now be appended a paragraph with the word "test"

```
<h2>Greetings</h2>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="inner">
      Hello
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
      Goodbye
      <p>Test</p>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Check out jquery's documentation to find out more: http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 1):

This works by appending an image object.

```
$('<a>', {href:''}).append($('<img>', {src:''}).appendTo('body')
```